# VBA to select and copy specific text from a text box between two text strings in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, textbox

In excel I have a text box labeled textbox1. In this text box are 17 queries.  They are all separated by a start and end string.  Query 1 and 2 look like this in the text box as an example:

Query1_start

Select * from table1

Query1_end

Query2_start

Select * from table2

Query2_end

I am trying to go into textbox1 and select everything between Query1_start and Query1_end and copy it via VBA.  I can’t seem to find the syntax for this as everything I come across relating to textbox results in selecting all which I do not want.

When I try to record a macro where I am only selecting between Query1_start and Query1_end, it just shows that I am entering the text box and selecting but not showing what I am selecting.

UPDATE:

I did find some VBA code that would help with this, however, it is contingent on selecting all from the text box and pasting it into column A.

```
Sub SelectBetween()
    Dim findrow As Long, findrow2 As Long

    findrow = Range("A:A").Find("Query1_start", Range("A1")).Row
    findrow2 = Range("A:A").Find("Query1_End", Range("A" & findrow)).Row
    Range("A" & findrow + 1 & ":A" & findrow2 - 1).Select

End Sub
```

I still need VBA to go to "textbox1", then select all within "textbox1", then paste selection into column A of sheet1.

Answer (score 1):

What about something like:

```
Sub Test()

Dim BOX As String, STRNG As String
Dim POS1 As Long, POS2 As Long, X As Long

For X = 1 To 17
    BOX = Worksheets("Blad1").TextBox1.Value
    POS1 = InStr(1, BOX, "Query" & X & "_start")
    POS2 = InStr(1, BOX, "Query" & X & "_End")
    STRNG = Mid(BOX, Len("Query" & X & "_start") + POS1, POS2 - (POS1 + Len("Query" & X & "_start")))
    Debug.Print STRNG
Next X

End Sub
```

Comment: You might have some residual vbLF or vbCRLF characters left in the parsed string. The op didn't provide reliable formatting in the sample.

Comment: @Jeeped, True. Replace might fix that, but with data provided I will leave answer as is for now.